# Merge superglobal with dynamic name

Tags: php

The following code is working

```
<?php
print_r(array_merge(${"_".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']}, $_GET));
?>
```

But when I using this code in a function or class, there is a problem

```
<?php
class Request {
    public static function init() {
        return array_merge(${"_".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']}, $_GET);
    }
}

print_r(Request::init());
?>
```

The result return an empty array with 2 errors :

- **Notice:**  Undefined variable: _GET in on line 4
- **Warning:**  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in on line 4

The warning is logical, but I don't understand the notice. Did anyone ever met this problem? Is there a solution? A problem in PHP core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (bottom of page):

> Please note that variable variables **cannot be used** with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.

Instead of using variable of variable syntax, use: [$GLOBALS superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

```
<?php
class Request {
    public static function init() {
        return array_merge($GLOBALS["_".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']], $_GET);
    }
}

print_r(Request::init());
?>
```

Comment: It is a possibility but that does not answer the question. A solution that we had already discussed, ty.

Comment: Why It needs to use  $GLOBALS instead of $ sign ?

Comment: @RakeshSojitra: As documentation states, it won't work otherwise

Comment: Note. This code worked : array_merge(${"_GET"}, $_GET);.

And I don't see the note in php documentation, but $GLOBALS not working too...

Comment: @YohannTilotti: Sorry i messed up links this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php is where the not is written. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok but I don't understand why the following code working array_merge(${"_POST"}, $_GET);. It's a variable variable on globals.

Comment: But array_merge(${$post = "_POST"}, $_GET); not working. The warning in the documentation answer to my question. But I don't understand why this warning...

Comment: @YohannTilotti: Looking at the older versions of PHP, this is just like this feature works (look here: https://3v4l.org/YDdrr).

Comment: @AndrzejBudzanowski the difference beetween test1 and test2 is just so crazy !! (look here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b6e5ff217e02e624d2253b2e6e66a6bb256c05a)